# High profile doesn't support lossless

Tags: ffmpeg

I ran this command

```
$ ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -qp 0 -profile:v high outfile.mp4
x264 [error]: high profile doesn't support lossless
[libx264 @ 03f8b020] Error setting profile high.
```

So "high" profile will not work with "lossless". However now I would like to run a command that says "use highest possible quality that High profile can offer". My idea is

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -qp 1 outfile.mp4
```

but I would like to know of any better options.

Comment: Does it need to be the High profile? High 4:4:4 works with lossless, for example.

Comment: @slhck yes, the system I am using support up to High only.

Comment: Honestly I'd just use a fixed QP of 1, or a CRF of 1. It's visually lossless. You'd end up with a bitrate of ~20 MBit/s for 720p video.